# Cursor position glitch in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

So heres the problem, in IE6 the cursor/caret doesn't want to be in the right spot, relative to the text box.

Usually it is next to the letter you are typing, but for some reason its behind by 2 letters (see picture), and will be a big problem when I'm trying to click somewhere to retype.

Any ideas on what's wrong or how I can fix it?

[image: Cursor Glitch Picture]

Also The css and html behind the form (if it helps):

```
#q
{
position:absolute;
outline:none;
font-family:Sans,Arial,Verdana;
padding:3px 22px 3px 36px;
_padding:3px 22px 3px 36px;
border:3px solid #DDDDDD;
font-size:17px;
width:420px;
height:35px;
-moz-transform:skewX(-25deg);
-o-transform: skewX(-25deg);
-webkit-transform:skewX(-25deg);
transform:skewX(-25deg);
}

<input type="text" id="q" name="q" placeholder="The Empire State Building" autocomplete="off" />
```

Tell me if you need anything else,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Come to think of it, could it be something to do with the padding on #q?

Comment: Do you _really_ need to support IE6?

Comment: Glad you are still supporting IE6, All Hail Connor

Comment: Not really, but I'm trying to make it as compatible as possible, so if this can be fixed it would be nice

Comment: @Mr.Alien Developers who still support IE6 are allowing it to live on, which is a _very_ bad thing

Comment: Dude, don't bother. IE6 is over 10 years old.

Comment: And I was thinking my clients are Nazis for asking me to support IE7 ...

Comment: I know its not worth it, but some people still use IE6, which is really annoying... so just to be nice, I'm trying to make it work :P However, I will include a "Please upgrade browser" or "Have you heard of chrome?"

Comment: @Bojangles I second that.. -Connor, Don't think *People still use IE6*

Comment: Ah!, If I remove the skewing, it fixes the problem, but the skewing is my design, so... Is there any reason for this? @Mr. Alien Your right, but I promised myself cross browser compatibility, down to IE6... I now regret that, because it sucks so much

Comment: @Connor I bet no one will be having an access to IE6, even Developer tools don't give us an option anymore..

Comment: According to modern.ie, 4.4% still use it... And some article I was just reading tells me that they will be abandoning it in april 2014

Comment: @Connor you only need to look at large scale public sector services to see them still using IE6 (4.3% of IE users of our online application do). @Mr.Alien/@Bojangles Its not developers who are allowing it to live on, in a lot of cases it'll be govermental red-tape, and IT services not wanting to embrace change.

Comment: My first thought is that IE6 is somehow recognizing the letters as being less in width... I don't think css transformations are properly supported in IE6 (your skew). Either way, this is just a *very minor* visual bug. Tbh nothing to worry about, especially considering that IE6 users are used to seeing fcked up websites... Final sidenote though: why not just use *font-style: italic;* ?

Comment: That Italics thing sounded like it would fix it, but yet again IE6 lets us down

Comment: Any other ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Ok, to preserve the skewed look, i removed it from the textbox and moved the button closer, thus solving all problems, and tricking the user into thinking it looks skewed :3

Comment: Thankyou everybody who helped